# Trigger an update with Azure PowerShell DSC Extension

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

I'm using the DSC Extension in Azure to configure the VM's and on first deployment that works fine. However, if I've made an error in the DSC script or need to amend it I am having trouble understanding how to force the VM to download the new configuration.

My DSC files are stored in Azure blob storage as required by the extensions, so I am uploading a new version of the zip here. Should this automatically trigger the VM to download the new file, or do I need to run a command to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should this automatically trigger the VM to download the new file

No, it won't automatically trigger.

Once you've [uploaded your configuration to the correct azure blob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn877980.aspx) you still need to push the configuration to your VM.

> do I need to run a command to do so

You can do this by using the [Set-AzureVMDscExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn832942.aspx) cmdlet.

Comment: I've tried using the Set-AzureVMDSCExtension cmdlet, but this returns an error saying there is already an extension with the same name installed (i'm using the ARM version of the cmdlet)

Comment: @Sam Try updating your DSC Extension, that sounds suspiciously like a bug [fixed in v2.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2015/06/17/azure-dsc-extension-v2-0-released.aspx). If that doesn't help DSC logs to the following 2 folders by default: C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.0.0.0
 and C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.0.0.0 on the local machine, perhaps there's more information there.

Comment: ok, I'm stuck at a different error now, the Set-AzureVMDscExtension refuse to recognise the resource group exists. If I do get-azureresourcegroup with that name it finds it fine, but the Set-AzureVMDscExtension  says it does not exist